# Chrome 45 does not display authentication dialog

Tags: google-chrome, http, authentication

I've set up a website with basic HTTP authentication. If I go there with IE 11 or Firefox 38, I get the expected dialog asking for credentials. If I attempt to go there with Chrome 45, it immediately gives me an "Authorization Required" error page and never asks me for credentials. This happens even after I restart the browser or the whole computer.

I've done the following things:

- Set all of my security zones in my IE/Windows Internet Options to prompt for username and password, as I understand that Chrome for Windows uses those settings.
- Tried making sure popups are enabled for the host I'm going to.
- Checked to see if maybe incorrect credentials were saved (there are no saved passwords for the host I'm going to).
- Dug through the Settings page for Chrome itself and found nothing else useful.
- Going to the desired address and putting the credentials into the URL (`http://user:password@host.com/page.html`).

No dice yet, I'm about to pull my hair out.

I'd like to note here that, for one, I cannot give the URLs I'm trying to access, as they are not public. Two, there are some domain-based policies put into place and I can't change some settings in Chrome (this is a corporate machine). I'm wondering if there's something I've missed that could, at the very least, explain why it's doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...And right as I finished writing this, I stumbled on something I DID miss. It looks like the policies set by my domain administrators have Chrome's [`AuthSchemes`](https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthSchemes) policy set to just `negotiate`, so it just doesn't bother with basic authentication. Looks like I need to talk to the IT department...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but was having trouble locating where Chrome stores this setting. On OS X, it's in `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`.

You can check if you're impacted by this by reading the `AuthSchemes` key:

`defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`

If it is an IT policy, it will get re-applied, but you can test if this is the issue by making sure `AuthSchemes` is set properly and restarting Chrome:

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist AuthSchemes basic,digest,ntlm,negotiate`

Comment: This fixed it for me in chrome 94 where it happened all of the sudden. 5 years after this answer was posted. I wonder why Chrome suddenly decided to change something there?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, Chrome didn't show save dialogue after I entered basic auth on a specific website. However, it did save login/password from the actual website I visited. I resolved this issue by deleting the existing login/password for this website from "Settings > Manage Password" and restarted Chrome. After this, the save dialogue for basic auth showed up.

I think this happens when you have a saved password on a website and add a basic auth later.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, this is what a `basic auth` prompt looks like:

[image]

Group Policy settings for Chrome and Edge:

[image]

[image]